# Managed class libraries cant be debugged when a native app is launched

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-2012

In visual studio 2005 we could build managed class libraries and debug them by setting the start external program path to our native application. The native app would create and run the managed code through com.

In visual studio 2012 the same process does not seem to work. When the native app is launched nothing appears to be loaded in the modules window.

Detaching the debugger and re-attaching to the running process causes the modules to be loaded and the managed class libraries can now be debugged.

How can i get the modules loaded automatically?

Comment: It works the exact same way in VS2012.  You probably just forgot to enable unmanaged debugging in your .NET project.

Comment: mmm enabling native code debugging loads all the native modules but no managed modules are loaded

Comment: Well, an obvious reason for that is the native code not being able to load the managed modules.  Taking shortcuts on COM error checking is a very common mistake.  You've got the debugger working now, better use it.

Comment: @HansPassant : I think you're being a bit dismissive, VS2012 _does_ work in a different way to VS2005; it uses the CLR 4.0 engine, which means it can't attach/detect automatically when a native application is using/targeting .NET < 4.0. This is a known issue (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

This happens when a native application launches a version of the .NET Framework that uses a different CLR to that of the tool version of Visual Studio.

For example, if your native application uses .NET 2.0 and you're using VS2012 then you need to manually point the debugger towards the correct version of the framework.

You can do this by adding a [native application].exe.config file that specifies the CLR version, for example (to .NET 2.0 - 3.5, CLR 2.0):

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <!-- Required for automatic Module debugging. -->
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

This is a known issue, if you want to find out more:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrehal/archive/2010/04/29/can-t-hit-breakpoints-in-a-plug-in-or-can-t-debug-net-2-0-3-0-3-5-from-a-mixed-mode-exe-project-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx